# Push values to array as separate key value pairs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, attributes

I have a project where I'm adding values from an attribute (comma separated integers) on a particular cell in each row of a table to an array in JS.

I know that if I create an array called myArray, then use `myArray.push(121840,121841);` the `myArray.length` result would be 2. This is what I expected. I had assumed (incorrectly) that since the value of the numbers attribute was the same format, e.g.: `numbers="121840,121841"`, then the result would be the same using `myArray.push($(this).attr('numbers'));`, but I was mistaken as the length of that array is 1, instead of 2.

See below an example of what I'm trying to do and the issue I'm encountering.

Given a table like this where I'm grabbing the values from the last cell's numbers attribute:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tbody emp-id="02" class="" name="Steve Smith">
      <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Steve Smith</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="total" numbers="121856,121860">2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody emp-id="01" name="Marky Mark">
      <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Marky Mark</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td class="total" numbers="121840,121841">2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My JS would is:

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  $(this).find('td:last').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('numbers')) {
        numbers.push($(this).attr('numbers'));
      names.push($(this).parents("tbody").attr('name'));
    }
  });
});
```

In the above example, the array has the correct number values stored, (121856,121860,121840,12184), but the length is given as 2 as each cell's values was added as a single element, such that number[0]=121856,121860, instead of 121856.

How would I correct this so that each integer within the attribute is added as a single element?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jacbhg0n/3/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You assumed wrong. Commas inside strings don't turn into argument separators. The string is just one value and it's treated literally. Use `split()` to convert it to an array, then use `.concat()`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  When I do this, however, it only adds the last cell's value to the array when I use: tickets = $(this).attr('numbers').split(",").concat();  If I use  numbers.push($(this).attr('numbers').split(",").concat()); then it still shows the array's length incorrectly.  How can I make this work inside the loop that loops through each cell and adds the values to the array?  Or can you please update my JSFiddle with what you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve that by splitting the numbers attribute string by using [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method while pushing it into the `numbers` array.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const numbers = [];
const names = [];

$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  $(this).find('td:last').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('numbers')) {
        numbers.push($(this).attr('numbers').split(','));
      names.push($(this).parents("tbody").attr('name'));
    }
  });
});

console.log(numbers.flat());
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tbody emp-id="02" class="" name="Steve Smith">
      <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Steve Smith</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="total" numbers="121856,121860">2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody emp-id="01" name="Marky Mark">
      <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Marky Mark</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td class="total" numbers="121840,121841">2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I had previously tried this. Although it adds the correct values, it does not split each value to it's own element.  So when I do this, with two cells and 4 total values (two per cell), the array's length still shows as 2, instead of 4.  Barmar's comment above seems to work, however I'm not sure how to loop through and add values using it.  Here's an example of your implementation still returning the array's length as 2, instead of 4: http://jsfiddle.net/jacbhg0n/4/

Comment: @B4THC4T `numbers.flat().length` will give you `4` not `2`.